# One to many mapping using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am beginner to dealing with database.Currently, I am using a PostgreSQL database.

This is post request model where I am getting a list of question.

```
public class QuestionListRequest {


List<QuestionRequest> questionList;

public List<QuestionRequest> getQuestionList() {
    return questionList;
}

public void setQuestionList(List<QuestionRequest> questionList) {
    this.questionList = questionList;
}
```

This is my Question table where I have to store the Question getting about post request.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "ns_question_b")
 public class Question extends DomainObject {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "question_gen")
@TableGenerator(name = "question_gen", table = "question_id_gen", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "QuestionId_Gen", initialValue = 100000, allocationSize = 1000)
@Id
@Column(name = "question_id")
private BigInteger questionId;

@Column(name = "question_text")
private String questionText;

@Column(name = "question_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private QuestionType questionType;

@Column(name = "question_timeout")
private Double questionTimeout;

@Column(name = "marks")
private Double marks;

@Column(name = "negative_mark")
private Double negativeMark;

@Column(name = "question_position")
private Double questionPosition;

@Column(name = "question_options")
private String questionOptions;

@Column(name = "subject")
private String subject;


public Question() {
    super();
}

public Question(BigInteger questionId, String questionText, QuestionType questionType, Double questionTimeout, Double marks, Double negativeMark, Double questionPosition, String questionOptions, String subject, Answer answer) {
    super();
    this.questionId = questionId;
    this.questionText = questionText;
    this.questionType = questionType;
    this.questionTimeout = questionTimeout;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.negativeMark = negativeMark;
    this.questionPosition = questionPosition;
    this.questionOptions = questionOptions;
    this.subject = subject;


}

public Question(String createdBy, Timestamp creationDate, int version, Timestamp lastModifiedDate,
                String lastModifiedBy, RecordStatus recordStatus) {
    super(createdBy, creationDate, version, lastModifiedDate, lastModifiedBy, recordStatus);
}

public BigInteger getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(BigInteger questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

public String getQuestionText() {
    return questionText;
}

public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
}

public QuestionType getQuestionType() {
    return questionType;
}

public void setQuestionType(QuestionType questionType) {
    this.questionType = questionType;
}

public Double getQuestionTimeout() {
    return questionTimeout;
}

public void setQuestionTimeout(Double questionTimeout) {
    this.questionTimeout = questionTimeout;
}

public Double getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public void setMarks(Double marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}

public Double getNegativeMark() {
    return negativeMark;
}

public void setNegativeMark(Double negativeMark) {
    this.negativeMark = negativeMark;
}

public Double getQuestionPosition() {
    return questionPosition;
}

public void setQuestionPosition(Double questionPosition) {
    this.questionPosition = questionPosition;
}

public String getQuestionOptions() {
    return questionOptions;
}

public void setQuestionOptions(String questionOptions) {
    this.questionOptions = questionOptions;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
```

Now my question is How to store all the question one by one in the question table on a single calling with database? 
I find many solution but there is only row to row mapping and I don't want this. I want all the question will directly stored in a Question table in a single calling.

Comment: You create a method, looping through your question requests, creating a Question for each of the questions, and calling persist() on each of them. And you call that method.

Comment: @JBNizet can you tell me with a example how to implement persist().

Comment: EntityManager.persist() is the standard JPA method used to... persist an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about your question, the heading says about One to Many issue but explanation is not clear. 
If you require to save the objects in a batch, you can add all questions to a list, add it to session and flush it at a certain limit.

Need to set this property,

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
```

And implement following code,

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

This is taken from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html